# Can't understand how Bootstrap is aligning elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm a new web-developer (not a new eng, just new to web) and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get elements on my page to align properly.

I want the elements to take up the entire horizontal space and be stacked vertically. However, they are appearing right next to one-another.

I'm using Bootstrap 4, and here is the HTML I wrote.

`base.html` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- Meta tags avoided for simplicity --> 

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<!-- Nav bar code ignored for simplicity -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h1 class="mt-5">My web page</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col col-lg-12">        
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The `block content` above is this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h5>{{ title }}</h5>
<form class="form-inline" action="{% url url %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="list-group">
    {% for question in questions %}
        <li class=list-group-item>
            <div>
                <p> {{ question }} </p>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> No
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary my-2">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I want the list to take up the whole width and the `submit` to be below the list. However, they appear right next to one-another.

Would appreciate some input on what's going on here and how I can fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Which element you want to be stacked one above the other ?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma I would like the `title` at the top, `form` after that (extended to full width) and the `submit` at the end.

Comment: i told you your mistakes in bootstrap’s design. please refer my answer. it should work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `form-inline` class from the form and made the element with `list-group` class a `ul` instead of a div.  `li` should have a `ul` parent. Thats the correct markup.

```html
<head>

  <!-- Meta tags avoided for simplicity -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <!-- Nav bar code ignored for simplicity -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="mt-5">My web page</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col col-lg-12">
        <h5>{{ title }}</h5>
        <form action="{% url url %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <ul class="list-group">
            {% for question in questions %}
            <li class=list-group-item>
              <div>
                <p> {{ question }} </p>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Yes
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> No
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>

            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Submit</button>
        </form>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always define a new id to override the default alignment set by bootstrap class. The problem you have can be simply solved as in the other answer, but for similar problems in the future where you have multiple classes with overlapping properties, you can use this.

```
//CSS
#block {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}

//HTML
<div class="class1 class2 class3" id="block">
   <!--The content here-->
</div>
```

This is a quick and solid fix because the properties of an ID are given preference over that of a class.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help - my only thing is that I think I've made a mistake somewhere in my HTML and I'd like to fix that. Reading the Bootstrap docs, it seems that `container` should by default extend to the full-width, due to Flexbox impl.

Comment: Use Chrome DevTools to quickly view all inherited CSS properties for an element and enable/disable them. You'll find the property that is causing problem. Just override that by creating an ID.